# SQL Query display results with wind but it skips certain lines

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, dbvisualizer

I've got a table with 11 columns for track and field and I've created an SQL query that sorts the table by a specific event, age group and gender, takes out all the duplicates and keeps the one with the best result. For some events it also differentiates between the results that had wind readings and those that didn't as well as if the wind was over a certain speed.

```
 @export on;
@export set filename="/home/filename.csv" CsvColumnDelimiter=",";
select * from Results2015;

SELECT resu.Result,
       resu.Wind,
       resu.`Full Name`,
       resu.Province,
       resu.BirthDate,
       resu.Position,
       resu.Location,
       resu.Date
  FROM Results2015 resu
  JOIN (
               SELECT MIN(Result) BestResult,
                      Wind, `Full Name`, Gender,
                      Event, Agegroup
                 FROM Results2015
                GROUP BY `Full Name`, Gender, Event, Agegroup
       ) best   
           ON  resu.Result    = best.BestResult
          AND  resu.Wind      = best.Wind 
          AND  resu.`Full Name`  = best.`Full Name`
          AND  resu.Gender    = best.Gender
          AND  resu.Event     = best.Event
          AND  resu.Agegroup  = best.Agegroup
  WHERE resu.Event = '100m'
   AND resu.Gender = 'F'
   AND resu.Agegroup = 'Junior' 
   AND resu.Wind <> ''
   AND resu.Wind <= 2                    
 ORDER BY resu.Result asc;
```

It works quite well but I've noticed that it's been missing a lot of the results that includes wind readings and I have no idea why. Here's a sample of the table I use

```
Result  Wind    Full Name   Province    BirthDate   Position    Location    Date    Event   Gender  Agegroup
12.78   -3.6    Name 4      WPA         D.o.B       6           Bellville   3-Feb   100m    F       Junior
12.87   -3.6    Name 2      WPA         D.o.B       7           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    M       Youth
12.64   -0.8    Name 3      WPA         D.o.B       2           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Junior
12.02   -0.8    Name 4      WPA         D.o.B       1           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Junior
12.84   -0.8    Name 5      WPA         D.o.B       3           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Junior
13.07   -0.8    Name 6      WPA         D.o.B       4           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Junior
13.23   -0.8    Name 7      WPA         D.o.B       5           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Junior
13.71   -4.3    Name 8      WPA         D.o.B       1           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Junior
13.85   -4.3    Name 9      WPA         D.o.B       2           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Junior
14.33   -4.3    Name 10     WPA         D.o.B       3           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Junior
14.69           Name 11     WPA         D.o.B       4           Bellville   2-Feb   100m    F       Junior
13.11   -2.9    Name 12     WPA         D.o.B       1           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Sub-Youth
13.43   -2.9    Name 13     WPA         D.o.B       2           Bellville   8-Feb   100m    F       Sub-Youth
13.53   -2.9    Name 12     WPA         D.o.B       3           Bellville   14-Feb  100m    F       Sub-Youth
13.60   -1.5    Name 15     WPA         D.o.B       1           Bellville   14-Feb  100m    F       Sub-Youth
```

For some reason it completely skips Name 4 in the output. The data for Name 4 is exactly the same as the other entries and it'll display those, but it completely excludes Name 4 as well as other entries, but only those that have windreadings as far as I can tell.

If I add Wind to the GROUP BY part for

```
GROUP BY `Full Name`, Gender, Event, Agegroup, Wind
```

It does display all the correct results, but then there are a lot of duplicates that I want to avoid.

Any idea on what's happening?

I use DbVisualizer Pro for all my SQL queries

SQLFiddle Sample here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8958/1
The problem lies with Tamza Bay not showing in the output

Comment: Having the same problem with both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: Please update your sample data with column headings. Currently we cannot say which column is wind or which column is what. Also try and make a http://www.SQLFiddle.com sample, this greatly helps everyone

Comment: Is your Wind column a varchar or a number, it isn't clear as your WHERE calsue specifies resu.Wind <> '' AND resu.Wind <= 2

Comment: Remove the Wind column from your subquery, I think it should then work.

Comment: @BerndLinde Ok cool I updated my post with the relevant information. I also did a SQLFiddle sample here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/688584/3

Comment: @SteveFord My wind collumn is a DECIMAL(2,1) value but I guess it can be varchar if it has to be. I took it out and I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Name 4 is in AgeGroup 'Youth', not 'Junior' as your query specifies.

EDIT after proper data added and fiddler played with:

This is your query:

(Edit2 - query deleted for space/)

The difference is your GROUP BY on the inner query. You had not specified Wind as part of it. Most DBMSs will error on that but MySQL doesn't. It also does some odd things with queries with malformed GROUP BY's - i.e. queries with a group by which do not include all the un-aggregated columns in the select. In this case, it caused that GROUP BY to return the 2.4 wind speed which then gets excluded. It's a known 'feature' of MySQL.

EDIT 2:
I changed te fiddle to include this query:

```
       SELECT MIN(`Result`) `BestResult`,
              `Full Name`, `Gender`,
              `Event`, `Agegroup`
         FROM `Results2015`
        GROUP BY `Full Name` , `Gender`, `Event`, `Agegroup`;
```

...which is your inner query and used to select the correct result from the full table. This gave a best result of 11.64 for Tamza Bay, which is indeed the best result. However, the wind in that race was 2.4 and so the outer Where excludes it. That's why.

Possibly you need to include the outer where in the inner query:

```
               SELECT MIN(`Result`) `BestResult`,
                      `Full Name`, `Gender`,
                      `Event`, `Agegroup`
                 FROM `Results2015`
  WHERE `Event` = '100m'
   AND `Gender` = 'F'
   AND `Agegroup` = 'Junior' 
       AND `Wind` <> ''
   AND `Wind` <= 2    
                GROUP BY `Full Name` , `Gender`, `Event`, `Agegroup`
```

Basically, make sure the inner query reyturns the results you want for the people, and then slot it into the main query.

Comment: Doesn't matter, name 4 also has a result as a Female Junior around the 4th line in the example table. Check here for the SQLFiddle sample http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/688584/3

Comment: I presume that you're talking about  Jank van Wank ? If so, she is appearing in the fiddler you've linked to. (It would help if you'd linked to the fiddler in the question, and specified which name the problem was with.)

Comment: Thanx I've edited my question. The problem lies with Tamza Bay not showing in the output even though she is both a Junior and a Female.

Comment: As soon as I add Wind to the GROUP BY query then I start getting multiple listings for the same person which I'd like to avoid http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb6db/1

Comment: OK. Take Wind out of the inner query altogether, and remove it from the ON list.

Comment: Did that, got the same result as earlier where Tamza Bay is left out http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8958/1